# How we can parse OPML String

Tags: android, parsing, opml

I got the following String as response when I post the url via HttpPost. My problem is how can I parse this string.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<opml version="1">

    <head>
    <status>200</status>
        </head>

    <body>

<outline type="object" text="account">

<account>

  <guide_id>u36710162</guide_id>

  <username>xyz</username>

  <session_id>9d28d854-bd31-4bba-9a5f-4e5cd88edaac</session_id>

  <first_name />

  <last_name />

  <email>xyz@gmail.com</email>

</account>

</outline>

    </body>

</opml>
```

How can I get the status, guide_id, username, session_id, first_name, last_name and email from this string.

Thanks in Advance ...!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a XML format response. You can parse it by **[SAXParser](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-sdk-build-a-simple-sax-parser/)**, [**DOMParser**](http://vikaskanani.wordpress.com/2011/09/15/android-simple-xml-dom-parser-example-for-reading-response-from-inputstream/) or **[Xmlpullparser](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/xmlpull/v1/XmlPullParser.html)**.

About `status` that you can get it from HTTP itself

```
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpRequest);
response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode()
```

*Note: Consider `<account>` as your parent tag.*

Comment: can you give any sample code ...!!! I want to be parse status also, bcz by this I would be get idea the response is correct or not ...!!!

Comment: Thanks a lot. Now I have done it. But the posted code by you I have already done. But the given link is very useful.